# How to implement the Delphi protected member access trick in C++ builder?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I need access to TControlItem.InternalSetLocation which is protected. I Delphi you would do

```
type
  THackControlItem = class(TControlItem);
```

How do you do this in C++ Builder?

Comment: Even in Delphi, this only works for protected members, not private.  Fwiw.

Comment: Only way to access private members is via RTTI, AFAIK. The hack you mention is called "The Protected Hack" for a reason ;-). It only works with protected members.

Comment: yes. sorry. I fixed the question.

Comment: @HeartWare: RTTI only if RTTI is enabled for private members. There are helper hacks (still, even after the class helper bug was more or less closed). These don't work in C++, of course. So I would do this in Delphi, expose the values so C++ can access them. I blogged about this: http://rvelthuis.blogspot.com/2018/01/accessing-private-methods-of-another.html

Comment: In C++, you can access protected members too, in a descendant class. To access them from outisde the class, you'll just have to write an extra descendant class that exposes the values you are interested in.

Comment: Or you can use friend class : http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Friends_Of_Classes

Comment: @Vancalar: indeed. But only in a descendant class, which is similar to exposing again.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis: no, that's not correct: ( from the source above) : "A friend F of a class X is a function or class, although not a member function of X, with full access rights to the private and protected members of X. " . It may be ANY class.

Comment: @Vancalar: say I want to access a protected member of class TEdit. Since TEdit did not declare my class as friend, only a descendant of TEdit can do that. So you need a descendant.

Comment: @Vancalar Friend is usable only if you have access and will to change the source code of the class you want to access.... in this case that would mean changing the VCL/FMX or whatever and I would not do it as it could cause problems latter ... for example you upgrade compiler version or move to another machine or reinstall ...  so Descendant is much more sane way of doing this contained in own source code files...

Comment: Spektre & Rudy: Of course nobody would change vcl sources to do that, THackControlItem is descendant of TControlItem anyway, I just wanted to clarify that friend class in general doesn't work  "But only in a descendant class," Cheers

Comment: Not relevant in this case, but strictly speaking as well as RTTI you can also contrive access to **private** members by declaring and type-casting a memory layout compatible overlay class which redeclares private members with greater visibility.  NOTE: This is even dirtier than the "protected hack" (and I've never tried it in CPPB) but it can be done in extremis desperado.  http://www.deltics.co.nz/blog/posts/825

Answer (score 2):

As in Delphi, you need to inherit the class but also override and make public the protected function. However, I wouldn't recommend to use it in production code.

```
class THackControlItem : public TControlItem
{
public:
    void __fastcall InternalSetLocation(int AColumn, int ARow, bool APushed, bool MoveExisting)
    {
        TControlItem::InternalSetLocation(AColumn, ARow, APushed, MoveExisting);
    }
};
```

In the program

```
TControlItem* ci = ...;
static_cast<THackControlItem*>(ci)->InternalSetLocation(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice trick I think [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau) showed me but can not find the QA anymore...

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef _TDirectMemoryStream
#define _TDirectMemoryStream
class TDirectMemoryStream:TMemoryStream // just for accessing protected SetPointer
    {
public:
    void SetMemory(BYTE *ptr,DWORD siz) { SetPointer(ptr,siz); Position=0; };
    };
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You simply create new class that is descendant of the class you want to access. Now just add get/set functions for the protected members ...

Now usage:

```cpp
TMemoryStream *mem=new TMemoryStream(); // original class instance you want to access

// overtype to our new class and access/use you get/set ...
((TDirectMemoryStream*)(mem))->SetMemory(hdr->lpData,hdr->dwBytesUsed);

delete mem; // release if not needed anymore
```

I am using it btw to feed a memory stream with custom memory data `hdr` coming from vfw camera so I can properly decode it using `TJPEGImage` class instead of writing the data into file and loading it back each frame ...

Here another example:

```cpp
class A
    {
protected:
    int x;
public:
    int getx(){ return x; }
    };

class hack_A:A
    {
public:
    void setx(int _x){ x=_x; }
    };

void test()
    {
    A a;
    hack_A *ha=(hack_A*)&a;
    ha->setx(10);
    a.getx(); // print the x somwhere
    }
```

However this will not work for private members ... In such case its doable too but requires access to `A` source code:

```cpp
class A
    {
protected:
    int x;
private:
    int y;
public:
    int getx(){ return x; }
    int gety(){ return y; }
    friend class hack_A;        // but this one requires access to A soourcecode
    };

class hack_A:A
    {
public:
    void setx(int _x){ x=_x; }
    void sety(int _y){ y=_y; }
    };

void test()
    {
    A a;
    hack_A *ha=(hack_A*)&a;
    ha->setx(10);
    ha->sety(20);
    a.getx(); // print the x somwhere
    a.gety(); // print the x somwhere
    }
```

Comment: Nice to know. But in my case won't work because I will have to re-implement InternalSetLocation which needs access to private fields (not methods).

Comment: @Rigel does not matter you just either write your custom code as a method of the descendant class or you add get/set for each variable you need into it ... if you take a look at the code of mine I am accessing both method `SetPointer`  and variable `Position` from the original class. If yo make the get/set methods a public one you can easily use them outside the class ...

Comment: in InternalSetLocation i need to write to FPushed which is private. It has a getter (function TControlItem.GetPushed: Boolean) but it has NO setter. How do I write to FPushed in this case?

Comment: @rigel You just write setter into the descendant class ... the same way I added the `SetMemory`  into mine...

Comment: You mean, I redeclare FPushed in my descendant class and write a getter and setter for it? You probably have a point, but I miss it.

Comment: @Rigel I added another example that better mimics what you are describing

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant all the time: in my case the x variable is PRIVATE. The compiler will generate an error when I try to access it. So, your code is nice, but it will only work for protected members. InternalSetLocation is protected but it needs to access FPushed whic is PRIVATE :)    :(

Comment: @Rigel see the last example ... in such case the only way of doing this is add your hack class as a friend ... modifying the VCL/FMX